# Loop through Data GridView and Get all Selected Rows ID then Delete from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

I have a DataGridView that get data from SQL database. I want to use user deleting row event to loop across all selected Ids and delete from the database. Here is my code:

```
private void dgvCashbook_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{  
   DialogResult delete = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure To Delete", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
   if (delete == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
     if (dgvCashbook.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value != DBNull.Value)                                      
     {
       SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Form1.constring);
       DataGridViewRow dgvRow = dgvCashbook.CurrentRow;
       SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand("simpcaDeleteRecord", myConnection);
       cmdDataBase.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(dgvCashbook.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value));
       myConnection.Open();
       cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();                  
      }
    }           
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a command builder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) along with the code below.

There a four types of commands 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Update 4) Insert.

A command builder takes the select command and creates the other three.  For the `AcceptChanges()` to work all four command types are needed. Try the following :

```cs
SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand("simpcaDeleteRecord", myConnection);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dataTable);
dataTable.Clear();
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but its not clear to me. I am Windows Application

Comment: The best way is to make the datatable the source of the DGV.  Then the rows of the table and DGV are the same.  Using an adapter creates links between the table and the database so when you delete a row from the table the Accept Change will delete the row of the database.